# When was the compact cube charger introduced for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, charger

Does anyone know when the compact cube charger was introduced for the iPhone?

I am looking for an official source, either from Apple's website or an industry magazine / web article.

It was 2008 at the latest; I did find [an Apple webpage on the 2008 recall of the AC mains prongs coming loose.](https://www.apple.com/support/usbadapter/exchangeprogram/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cube charger was released with the iPhone 3G on July 11, 2008. [A review of the 3G mentions it](https://www.cnet.com/products/apple-iphone-3g/review/):

> The plug is pleasantly smaller than on the original iPhone's, but it's compatible with a standard USB cable.